# Android Activity Rotated

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having a problem with an Activity being rotated after I get back from another that has a different screen orientation.

Allow me describe the steps to reproduce this behavior:

1.I have an Activity declared in the Manifest like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".JobActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_job"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

As you can see, `screenOrientation` is set to `portrait`

2. Inside this Activity I launch another Activity with the following Intent:

   `Intent jobDetailsIntent = new Intent(mActivity, JobDetailActivity.class);
   startActivity(cameraIntent);`

This Activity screen orientation is declared to be `landscape`.

```
<activity
android:name=".JobDetailActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@style/ThemeFullscreen" />
```

3. The Activity `JobDetailActivity` when pressing a button, start another Activity waiting for a result.

`startActivityForResult(getIntent(activity), requestCode);`

This other Activity is declared as `portrait`

```
<activity
android:name=".QuestionsActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/ThemeFullscreen.Color" />
```

4. When I get the result from this other Activity, and after doing a couple of things, I call `finish` in order to return to the first Activity (`JobActivity`).

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // Some other stuff
    this.finish();
}
```

}

At this point, when I get back to `JobActivity` I get to see the Activity in `landscape` (Remember it was declared as `portrait`) for a second and then returns to the original position.

To sum up:

`A (portrait) -> B (landscape) -> C (portrait)`

After receiving result from C and going back to B

`A (portrait) -> B (landscape)`

After calling `finish` from B

`A (landscape)`

After a second

`A (portrait)`

Any ideas why this may be happening? Thank you all, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: On the last two steps: while A was still in the landscape view, did it only cover half of the landscape screen before it finally adjusted into the portrait view?

Comment: It covered the whole screen in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this code:

```
Intent jobDetailsIntent = new Intent(mActivity, JobDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

There is a difference between the name of intent declare and intent used to start the activity.

Maybe the problem is here.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh shut, I didn't noticed that. It's definitely `jobDetialsIntent` not `cameraIntent`. Sorry about that.